# Why Cant i delete rows in a table

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-delete

I cant delete rows in a table
it doesn't come up with any error messages
con has been used on other statements and works just fine
textbox1 is read-only and gets input from a listbox filled with the values of the "Driver" column
and check() is just to refresh the listbox containing the values

```
        con.Open()

    Try
        success = True
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Driver WHERE Driver='" & TextBox1.Text & "';", con)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        success = False
    End Try
    If success Then
        MsgBox("Success")
    End If
    con.Close()
    check()
```

Comment: Please use query parameters instead of string concatenation, or you'll be at risk of SQL injection attacks, or accidents.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never execute the command. Add a call to `SqlCommand::ExecuteNonQuery`

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Driver WHERE Driver='" & TextBox1.Text & "';", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' added
```

That said you should **not** use string concatenation when adding values to your sql statement. Instead use Parameters which prevents sql injection attacks.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Driver WHERE Driver= @driver", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@driver", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text ' add parameter
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' added
```

---

#### Assumption

`Driver` is a column inside a table with the same name `Driver`. If this is not the case then you do not understand tables and columns or the DELETE statement which in its basic form is `DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE [condition on one or more columns]`

Comment: oh whoopsie
i cant believe i forgot to do that
and thx for the extra info 
Thanks a lot :D